# GitHub API "combined status" is always Pending

Tags: github-api

I am trying to get the status of a repo. From Github doc it should be one of the following:

> failure |  pending  | success

This is very useful for checking if an automated build passed or failed.

Using this API to get a repo combined status:

https://docs.github.com/en/rest/commits/statuses?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-the-combined-status-for-a-specific-reference

```
curl -L \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github+json" \
  -H "Authorization: Bearer $KEY"\
  -H "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/supercobra/st/commits/main/status
```

Response:

```
{
  "state": "pending",
  "statuses": [

  ],
  "sha": "dbf9e48d06917c06b859823008444f3baebd58f4",
  "total_count": 0,
...
```

Github response is always a `pending` state regardless of the repo so I am inclined to think that there is a bug in the Github API. Anybody has a fix or workaround?

Comment: Github issue: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/58407